# connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql

How to allow access to the same mysql both from remote host and local host? because either of them seems to work not both

Comment: You need to add both hosts.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-system.html

Comment: I'm sure this is a dead question, but you need to supply more info eneyed.  Are you trying to connect to the remote host with root access?  If so, you need to "Enable root access from remote machines" *(which is not recommend though for security reasons)*

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the [common causes of Access-Denied Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html) ..?